# Converting pdf file into text in python ? i have used pypdf2 and pdfminer as well they wern't working properly

Tags: python, pdf

```py
import fitz
file = "C:\\Users\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\example.pdf"
doc = fitz.open(file)
for page in doc:
    text = page.getText("text")
    print(text)
```

above codes works good but i am unable to extract table data properly

Comment: Extracting table data is a good deal more difficult th9n you seem to imagine. A PDF has no concept of a *table* in the way that an HTML document or a Word document has. All it knows about are letters or numbers positioned on the page, with maybe some lines thrown in. You could try Camelot.

Answer (score 0):

From source https://pdf.wondershare.com/pdf-knowledge/pdf-to-text-python.html,
You can use the package pdftotext by simply running `python -m pip install pdftotext` in your terminal. Now to actually use this, its as simple as...

```
#Import pdftotext
import pdftotext

#render pdf file
with open("Target.pdf", "rb") as f:
pdf = pdftotext.PDF(f)

# Save output text to .txt file
with open('output.txt', 'w') as f:
f.write("\n\n".join(pdf))
```

Done!

Comment: is there any other way ,like i just wanna extract those tables only from pdf file not the entire text